# Maven run command for specific test suite

Tags: maven, automated-tests

i am trying to build maven command to run specific test:

i want to be able to execute this:

```
mvn test
mvn integration
mvn specificdata
```

so each test will go into a folder and run the suite

- src/test
- src/integration
- src/specificdata

`mvn test` works with the test folder but when i run

`mvn specificdata` i get

```
[ERROR] Unknown life-cycle phase "specificdata".
```

same for integration

how can i make mvn run these tests independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in the way you describe it.

`test` is a phase and as such, part of the standard lifecycle. Calling `mvn test` does not only run tests, but executes the phases before `test` as well.

The standard lifecycle also offers phases for integration tests, esp. `integration-test`. Integration tests are usually put into `src/test` as well and distinguished by a naming convention. But beware: Calling `mvn integration-test` will call all previous phases (including `test`, `compile`etc.) as well.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: then how can I do it? is there other tools I can use?

Comment: @yenk Why do you have these special requirements? Why not just run the tests with the build? You want something unusual and you probably have a reason for it.

Comment: because i have sensitive data and code to test based on clearance

Comment: The surefire plugin (for Maven tests) has a command line parameter `surefire.includesFile` which allows you to define a file that contains the list of tests you want to run. See https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html